# Solving the logarithmic inequality by using manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve this problem but stuck 
$$\log_x\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}<-1$$

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Can you take the log in a negative base?

While we are on the subject of undefined solutions, can we take the log of a negative number.  Can, $\frac {4x+5}{6−5x} < 0$

And what would be the implications of $x = 1$?  That would also be undefined

The domain of $\log_x \frac {4x+5}{6−5x}$ is $x\in(0,1)\cup(1,\frac 65)$

$\log_x \frac {4x+5}{6−5x}<(−1)$

Take the inverse log of both sides. 
What is going to happen to that inequality?  Does it stay the same, or does if flip?

If $x>1, x^a < x^b$ when $a<b$  when $x>1, x^a>x^b$ when $a<b$.  We must consider the two cases separately.

case $x>1:$
$\frac {4x+5}{6−5x}<x^{−1}\\
\frac {4x+5}{6−5x}<\frac {1}{x}\\
4x^2+5x < 6−5x\\
(4x - 2)(x+3)<0\\
x\in(-3,\frac12)$

But that contradicts that $x>1$

Note: when cross multiplying watch for the possibilities of flipping the inequalities when $x<0.$  Not the case here, so not a risk.

Case $0<x<1:$
$\frac {4x+5}{6−5x}>x^{−1}\\
\frac {4x+5}{6−5x}>\frac {1}{x}\\
4x^2+5x > 6−5x\\
(4x - 2)(x+3)>0\\
x>\frac 12$

$x\in (\frac12,1)$

Comment: When $0<x<1$, the function $\log_x(\cdot)$ is not increasing!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that $$\log_x\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}$$ is a real number iff $0<x<\frac{6}{5}$.

We know that $y=\log_a x$ is a monotoning increasing function for $a>1$ and motonotic decreasing if $0<a<1$.

So, from the definition: $\log_x A=-1 \iff x^{-1}=A $, we have two cases for the given inequality:

$$
\begin {cases}
1<x<\frac{6}{5}\\
\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}<x^{-1}
\end{cases} 
$$

$$
\begin {cases}
0<x<1\\
\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}>x^{-1}
\end{cases} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that for $x>0$, $x\not=1$, and $A>0$,
$$\log_x(A)=\frac{\ln (A)}{\ln(x)}$$
where $\ln$ is the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm).

In our case, for $x>0$, $x\not=1$, 
$$A=\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}>0\Leftrightarrow  x\in (0,1)\cup (1,6/5).$$

Now we have two cases.

1) If $1<x<6/5$, then $\ln(x)>0$ and the inequality is equivalent to
$$\ln \frac{4x+5}{6-5x}<-\ln(x)=\ln(1/x)
\Leftrightarrow \frac{4x+5}{6-5x}<\frac{1}{x}
\Leftrightarrow 4x^2+5x < 6−5x \Leftrightarrow  4x^2+10x < 6
$$
which is impossible for $x>1$.

2) If $0<x<1$, then $\ln(x)<0$ and the inequality is equivalent to
$$\ln\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}>-\ln(x)=\ln(1/x)
\Leftrightarrow \frac{4x+5}{6-5x}>\frac{1}{x}\Leftrightarrow  4x^2+10x >6\Leftrightarrow x\in (1/2,1).$$

We conclude that the inequality is satisfied iff $x\in (1/2,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x):=\frac{4x+5}{6-5x}.$

Firstly, let us work on domain restrictions:

- 1) $f(x)$ must be $>0$, (because the domain of any logarithm function is $(0,\infty)$; thus $-5/4<x<6/5.$
- 2) $x>0$ (because any basis of logarithms is positive).

Therefore, values of $x$ are restricted to open interval $I:=(0,6/5)$.

Taking the definition of a logarithm in base $b$:

$$\tag{1}\dfrac{\ln(f(x))}{\ln(x)}<-1 \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}(a) &if& 0<x<1&\ln(f(x))>-\ln(x)\Leftrightarrow f(x)>\frac{1}{x}\\(b) &if& 1<x<6/5&\ln(f(x))<-\ln(x)\Leftrightarrow f(x)<\frac{1}{x}\end{cases}$$

(we have used the increasing property of function $\ln$).

Can you conclude from there?

Comment: I had made a mistake that is now corrected.